# Visualizing a droppable field

Tags: interface-design

I'm currently working on a pure drag and drop part of my applications UI.

There are certain tools the user can drop the items into, to do certain things (Remove, rename, move)

Are there any good 'standard' ways of visualizing that a field is droppable?

Comment: I was unsure if this should be in ux.SE, but I guess it fits better in GD

Comment: I'd say it's the same as a hover effect. Once you start dragging highlight the target areas. Or, since drag and drop is a bit less common, maybe even animate it with something like dotted borders.

Comment: "droppable" isn't really anything specific. what you want to do is show that an item can be **moved or picked up** (unless you can find me a physical object that looks droppable).

Comment: @KMSTR I guess this children's toy is a good example on a physical object with the same anticipated behavior: http://i.imgur.com/bLBHGIU.png

Comment: You can also look at video games, when an item can be picked up in some games the character reaches out. You see that simplified with a hand cursor as well, just look at the hand tool (H) in Illustrator.